# Why is WP Query order by ASC not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

Any idea why ASC order isn't working here? Am I doing something wrong?

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'apartments',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'bedrooms',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
  );

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```

Comment: use echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; to show your sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should specify "meta_type" for this query. Referred to from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value